# NodeJS and mySQL error: "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

I'm running my vscode and node on wsl2 [wsl2 Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) but my XAMPP SQL database is running on Windows not in the wsl2 environment.

Is there a way to connect from my wsl2 to the Window's machine MYSQL server running on XAMPP.

Currently when I try connecting to MYSQL database from Node JS, I get this error:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
```

I have tried changing host to "localhost" and not declaring the port also but it fails with the same error.

The following is the code I am currently using:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Create connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: "3306",
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
});

//Connect
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to mySQL...');
    };
});

const app = express();

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server running on http://localhost:3000')
});
```

Comment: We need more information here, I would ask you:
1. Can you connect to your database through some SQL client? Or the terminal?
2. Have you tried to set a password for that user on the database? It has happened to me that I can't connect to the db from node until I set a password.